# Should have a 404 response to a GET request but received 200. Restlet

Tags: java, junit, httprequest, httpresponse, restlet

I've a RESTlet server running on my android device. It is configured fine. Now I'm jUnit testing it and this particular test is failing for no reason.

I've this URL:

`http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts?order=ASC&limit=10&offset=1` which is correct, I receive a 200 response as expected.

But then if I misspell the parameters in the URL I should get a 404 response. Using [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) extension for Chrome if I hit `http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts?oooooooorder=ASC&limit=10&offset=1` (note that "order" is misspelled) I receive a 404 as I should. Until here everything is fine.

The problem comes when I create a RESTlet client to make that `GET request` on my jUnit test, it receives a 200 response.

Here is my jUnit test method:

```
public void testGoodRequest() // Success, receives a 200 code.
{
    // Create the client resource
    ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts?order=ASC&limit=10&offset=1");
    Response response = resource.getResponse();

    Log.d(TAG, "Good: " + response.getStatus().getCode());

    assertTrue(response.getStatus().getCode() == 200);      
}
```

Adn this one should receive a 404 but receives a 200, eventho the same get request using Chrome's postman receives a 404:

```
public void testBadRequestWithOrderMisspelled()
{
    // Create the client resource
    ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts?oofdgrder=ASC&limit=10&offset=1");
    Response response = resource.getResponse();

    Log.d(TAG, "BadRequestWithOrderMisspelled: " + response.getStatus().getCode());

    assertTrue(response.getStatus().getCode() == 404); // Assert fails, receives 200 instead of 404     
}
```

And here is my Restlet handle method:

```
@Override
public void handle(Request request, Response response) {

    //final ContactList contactList = new ContactList(mContext);
    String type = request.getMethod().getName();

    String order = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm().getFirstValue("order");
    String limit = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm().getFirstValue("limit");
    String offset = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm().getFirstValue("offset");
    String query = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm().getFirstValue("query");

    if(!"order".equals(order) || !"limit".equals(limit) || !"offset".equals(offset) || !"query".equals(query))
    {
        // Show error
        response.setStatus(new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND, "Badly formatted URL."));
        return;
    } 
(...)
}
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I personally don't think it's a good idea to give 404 for bad/invalid parameters. I would recommend you to fix up the protocol to send error message (in Json or Xml) to the client and the client should handle the error accordingly.

Comment: I'm doing this because I'll be performing SQL queries on the device and I want to prevent unnecessary queries on it or consequent overwhelming of the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason that I don't know RESTlet client was probably the reason for my problem.

I switched over to an [android async http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) client and things are running smoothly.

Here is my code using async http client:

```
    SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();

    // Should be success
    client.get("http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET - ID: 1 - Success expected -> Got success");
            auxArray.add("1");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {
            super.onFailure(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
            Log.d(TAG, "GET - ID: 1 - Success expected -> Got failure");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which version of Restlet client were you using? I recommend our latest stable Restlet 2.2.0 version which directly relies on the HttpURLConnection. You can always run it in an Android AsyncTask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @JeromeLouvel I'm using Restlet 2.1. I've seen a new stable version (2.2) of Restlet for Android but haven't made the switch yet.

Answer (score 1):

404 is for resource `http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts` not found

WIKIPEDIA: **404 Not Found**
The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

if resource is there and proper input is not give for process

it will not give 404! [Read More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

plus as per following code, there are 2 things

1. you misspelled `limite`
2. you are comparing received values to Strings like `order` `offset`
   amd `limit`

i do not think that is what you want to achieve, you should be comparing it with some variables rather

```
if(!"order".equals(order) || !"limite".equals(limit) || !"offset".equals(offset) || !"query".equals(query))
    {
        // Show error
        response.setStatus(new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND, "Badly formatted URL."));
        return;
    }
```

Comment: But I'm explicitly returning a 404 response on my handler if there is a wrong input. If I hit that url on my browser I'll also get a 404 request.

Comment: well according to me you should not do that, playing with standard HTTP codes. second thing is what you are doing is `"order".equals(order)` will compare value of order attribute to `String` `"order"`, is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Exactly, I want to make sure that `order` variable is actually holding the value "order". Yes, meanwhile I found out that limit was misspelled as well, fixed it. Still getting 200 response code.
I'm doing this because I'll be performing SQL queries in the device and I want to prevent unnecessary queries on it or consequent overwhelming of the device.

Comment: i hope you know difference between `getFirst()` and `getFirstValue()` in this `request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm().getFirstValue("order")`

Comment: read here http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jee/api/org/restlet/util/Series.html#getFirst(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yup, I forgot that slightly detail that was also helping to have unexpected results. +1 added.
I ended up moving to `android async http` and it is working just fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tracked the HTTP request using tools and does the request reaches your handler before throwing the error?